# Request method 'GET' not supported but it's actually present in Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was developing a simple CRUD application, when i've encountered a this weird error. Weird, because in my controller class convenient `@RequestMapping` annotated method is present with request `GET` method mapping. The requested URI is `[context]/purchase/change/2`. The error is following:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'GET' not supported
```

and there is my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/purchase")
public class PurchasesController {

    //...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addPurchase(Model model, @PathVariable int userId) {
        //that method works with mapping ex. "context/purchase/add/1"
        return "purchase_update_add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPurchase(
            @ModelAttribute("purchase") PurchaseDTO purchaseDto,
            @PathVariable int userId) {

        //that works too

        return "redirect:/user/" + userId;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/change/${purchaseId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String changePurchaseDate(Model model, @PathVariable int purchaseId) {

        model.addAttribute("operation", "change");

        PurchaseDTO purchase = new PurchaseDTO();
        Purchase purchaseEntity = purchasesDAO.getPurchase(purchaseId);
        purchase.setDate(purchaseEntity.getDate());
        purchase.setId(purchaseId);

        model.addAttribute("purchase", purchase);

        return "purchase_update_add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/change/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changePurchaseDate(
            @ModelAttribute("purchase") PurchaseDTO purchaseDto,
            @PathVariable int userId) {
        Purchase purchase = purchasesDAO.getPurchase(purchaseDto.getId());
        purchase.setDate(purchaseDto.getDate());
        purchasesDAO.updatePurchase(purchase);
        return "redirect:/user/" + userId;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You've created a Path Variable with `${...}` syntax:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/change/${purchaseId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
                                 ^ $ is redundant
```

Use the correct `{...}` syntax instead:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/change/{purchaseId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Oh yeah. It's so true, thanks! I can't believe i missed that during inspections.